# AWS CLI : Windows CLI -- SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to create stack using below command on Windows **AWS CLI**

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name dockerApp --template-body file://./stack.json`
```

Here is **stack.json** contains my template definition

I am getting below error:

> Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load paramfile file://./stack.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/./stack.json'

Comment: Try `file://stack.json` if it is in the current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open command prompt as administrator and execute below command

`copy "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\botocore\vendored\requests\cacert.pem" "c:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\certifi"`

For more information, go through [aws-cli-issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2855)